# Onclick get element id result undefined jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I know this will mark as duplicate.. but i already try looking other post even i ask Mr. Google but i totally confuse.. i try use every sample on post but seems not all work..

What i'm trying to archive is.. when i click button jquery will show button id on alert popup. But i always got result undefined.

Here my sample code

PHP

```
<button class="myButton" name="testResultByName" data-value="testResultByDataValue" id="testResultByID">Click</button>
```

JQUERY and i put this code right before closing body `</body>` tag and already try on top right before closing head `</head>` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.myButton').click(function(event){
        var myButtonVar = $(this).prop('data-value');

        alert(myButtonVar);
        event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

I already try to use

```
$(this).prop('id');
$(this).prop('name');
$('.myButton').attr('data-value');
$('.myButton').attr('id');
$('.myButton').attr('name');
```

nothing work.. but if i use class like below it's work...

```
$('.myButton').prop('class');
```

then alert show class name "myButton" seems work.. i already use external jquery file too.. but nothing work.. already use `ready()` too but result still same..

did i miss something? oh and i use `jquery-1.11.3.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You [`$.data`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) instead of `.prop`, like so

```
$('.myButton').click(function(event){
    var myButtonVar = $(this).data('value');
    var buttonId = $(this).attr('id');

    console.log(myButtonVar);
    console.log(buttonId);
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/0jjdqt6e/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You get the value from the attr().

Please see the example code for the same

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.myButton').click(function(event){
        
        var myButtonVar = $(this).attr('data-value');
        alert("data-value = "+myButtonVar);
        
        myButtonVar = $(this).attr('id');
        alert("id = "+myButtonVar);
        
        myButtonVar = $(this).attr('name');
        alert("name = "+myButtonVar);
        
        myButtonVar = $(this).attr('class');
        alert("class = "+myButtonVar);
                
        
        event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="myButton" name="testResultByName" data-value="testResultByDataValue" id="testResultByID">Deposit</button>
```

Comment: We have tested it in local system its working fine. So please test and verify

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.myButton').on('click', function(){
    var btnValue = $(this).attr('data-value');
    alert(btnValue);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: why `attr` instead of `prop` ? ... why sometimes `attr` will return `undefined` like above question ?